# PHP XMLWriter skip empty tags

Tags: php, element, skip, xmlwriter

```
$xmlF->writeElement($fieldName, $fieldVal);
```

Currently, when `$fieldVal` is empty, above will output:

```
<FieldName/>
```

Is it possible to skip element entirely (other than with if's) when its value is empty?

Comment: What do you mean "other than with if's"? Like filtering? Depends on how you're getting the nodes... Are you using XPath?

Comment: I meant maybe built in XMLWriter optional argument that I might be not aware of

Comment: I see, sorry. There is no way, since an empty tag is completely valid XML. You need to check before adding it: `if ($fieldVal === "") { $xmlF->writeElement($fieldName, $fieldVal); }`

Comment: OK, I accept that 'if' condition is a way to handle this. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create condition for that:

```
if (!empty($fieldVal)) {
    $xmlF->writeElement($fieldName, $fieldVal);
}
```

Comment: For some reason this condition appear to be true when `$fieldVal` is 0 i.e. `<FieldName>0</FieldName>` is not output which is not desired

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I only changed condition to `if ($fieldVal !== "")`